# Address Chrome tabs inside different windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code for a Chrome extension which allows me to switch between the current and the previous tab:

```
function switchTabs() {
    let prevTab = tabHistory[currentTabId].prev;
    if (prevTab.id) { // Check if is dummy start.
        chrome.tabs.update(prevTab.id, {active: true});
}}
```

This works if both tabs are inside the same window.

However, it does not work if the two tabs are in different windows.

Could someone explain to me the difference and how I need to query the tabs if they are placed in different windows?

Entire code:

```
let tabHistory = {};
let currentTabId;
let currentTabJustRemoved = false; // No-use if `defaultTabClosingBehavior`.
let defaultTabClosingBehavior = true;

function init() {
    tabHistory[-1] = {id: null}; // Dummy start.
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        lastFocusedWindow: true,
    }, function(tab) {
        currentTabId = tab[0].id;
        tabHistory[currentTabId] = {id: currentTabId, prev: tabHistory[-1]};
        tabHistory[-1].next = tabHistory[currentTabId];
        validateHistory();
    });
}

async function switchTabs() {
  let prevTab = tabHistory[currentTabId].prev;
  if (prevTab.id != null) { // may be 0 in some browsers
    const {windowId} = await chrome.tabs.update(prevTab.id, {active: true});
    chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true});
  }
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    switchTabs()
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
    // After current tab is closed, this listener is triggered twice. Chrome
    // first switches to its default tab. Then, we switch to our last tab which
    // can be identified with `currentTabId`.
    if (currentTabJustRemoved) {
        currentTabJustRemoved = false;
        return;
    }
    if (info.tabId === currentTabId) {
        return;
    }

    let prevTabId = currentTabId || -1; // Might be dummy start.
    currentTabId = info.tabId;

    if (!tabHistory.hasOwnProperty(currentTabId)) { // Newly visited tab.
        tabHistory[currentTabId] = {id: currentTabId};
    }
    let currentTab = tabHistory[currentTabId];
    if (currentTab.prev) {
        currentTab.prev.next = currentTab.next;
        currentTab.next.prev = currentTab.prev;
    }

    let prevTab = tabHistory[prevTabId];
    prevTab.next = currentTab;
    currentTab.prev = prevTab;
    delete currentTab.next;
    validateHistory();
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, info) {
    if (tabHistory.hasOwnProperty(tabId)) { // Visited tab.
        // Remove tab from `tabHistory`.
        let removedTab = tabHistory[tabId];
        if (tabId === currentTabId) {
            // Current tab is removed. Switch to the last tab.
            delete removedTab.prev.next;
            currentTabId = removedTab.prev.id;
            if (!defaultTabClosingBehavior && currentTabId) {
                currentTabJustRemoved = true;
                chrome.tabs.update(currentTabId, {active: true});
            }
        } else {
            removedTab.prev.next = removedTab.next;
            removedTab.next.prev = removedTab.prev;
        }
        delete tabHistory[tabId];
    }
    validateHistory();
});

function validateHistory() {
    let current = tabHistory[-1];
    let path = current.id;
    while (current.next) {
        if (current.next.prev !== current) {
            console.error("Broken history!");
            console.error(currentTabId, tabHistory);
            return;
        }
        current = current.next;
        path = path + " => " + current.id;
    }
    console.debug(path);
}

init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also focus the tab's window:

```js
async function switchTabs() {
  let prevTab = tabHistory[currentTabId].prev;
  if (prevTab.id != null) { // may be 0 in some browsers
    const {windowId} = await chrome.tabs.update(prevTab.id, {active: true});
    chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true});
  }
}
```

P.S. For the deprecated ManifestV2 you'll have to either promisify it or use a callback:

```
chrome.tabs.update(prevTab.id, {active: true}, tab =>
  chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true}));
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tested this inside Chrome. It does remember the last two used tabs inside window 1 when I switch to another window 2 and back (to window 1). But if am on a tab inside window 1 and then go to a tab inside a window 2, and then trigger the extension function, it does not switch back to the tab inside window 1.

Comment: There's only one way to do it, which is shown here, so you need to debug it in [devtools for the background script](/a/10258029) and make sure it's actually called and there are no other errors.

Comment: I found this issue: https://i.imgur.com/43Ih2Nd.png Do you know what it means?

Comment: It means the value on the right is undefined, which can happen if you use the deprecated ManifestV2. Either switch to ManifestV3 or promisify the call explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I am still using ManifestV2. Do you mean I can only address tabs in different windows if I am migrating to v3?

Comment: ManifestV2 isn't Promise-based, so you have to use it differently, see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far! I migrated to v3 and it's working pretty well. I just noticed two weird glitches which I summarised in this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z-d5fb-NM0pP3T7S127P5Igyq5slrMKa/view?usp=drivesdk). Do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I can't say without seeing the entire code which may contain a mistake, otherwise it's a bug in the browser/OS.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my initial question and provided the entire code I am using.

Comment: I guess it's because service worker dies after 30 seconds since the last incoming event, you can either [keep it alive](/a/66618269) or [use chrome.storage for globals](/a/73090402). If this doesn't help you should debug your code in [background devtools](/a/10258029) with breakpoints.

Comment: Going to explore those, thank you for all your help!